# converting negative farenheit number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I can not get this code to convert a negative Fahrenheit value to a Celsius value using JavaScript. I'm assuming it is a problem with using either floor or isValid, but not sure. My code is successfully converting positive Fahrenheit values to Celsius, but not negative. this is also a program for converting fahrenheit to celsius, miles to kilometers and ounces to grams to clarify

```
   //alert("Input value validated as numeric: " + iv);
      var cT = document.getElementsByName("cType");
         if (cT[0].checked) {
             //to celsius
             if (isValid(iv,0)) {
             $("result").value = iv + " farenheit = " + FtoC(iv)  +    " celcius.";
             }
         }

  function FtoC (farenheit) {
      var C = (farenheit-32) * (5/9);
      return C;
  }
  function MtoK (miles) {
      var K = miles * 1.6;
      return K;
  }
  function OtoG (oz) {
      var g = oz * 28.35;
      return g;toFixed(3);
  }
  function isValid(val,floor) {
      if (val < floor) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: That function doesn't convert anything, it just tests if `val` is smaller than `floor`. By the way, it could be just `function isValid(val, floor){ return val < floor }`. That being said, please share your whole code for converting.

Comment: Hi amboitano, welcome to SO! I think we're missing a part of your code, you only put the `isValid` function, which does not have any converting happening.

Comment: hi guys! i updated the code to include everything so hopefully that helps clarify some things

Answer (score -1):

Here is a super-simple fahrenheit to celsius converter.

```js
const a = document.getElementById("answer");
const b = document.getElementById("butt");
const c = document.getElementById("convert");
var cels = 0;
b.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var fahr = Number(c.value);
  cels = (1.8*fahr) + 32;
  a.innerHTML = cels + "<sup>o</sup>C";
})
```

```html
<input id="convert" type="number" /><sup>o</sup>F
<button id="butt">Convert Me!</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```